# With regard to Mechanical Energy what forms of Potential energy are included?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

I've seen the **mechanical energy** of a system defined as **the sum of its kinetic and potential energies**. What forms of potential energy are included in this definition?  Gravitational and elastic potential energy are the ones typically featured in textbook examples but what about chemical potential energy or electrical potential energy?  They don't seem to fit under the umbrella of mechanical energy.

Comment: "What forms of potential energy are included in this definition?" You can define whatever you want to define. You seem to be asking an opinion poll. Like: "In your opinion, should electrical potential energy be classified as 'mechanical'."

Comment: almost all of the times, The only use of such mechanical energy concept is done is during conservation of mechanical energy, Which will even follow when you consider internal energy, electrostatic potential energy etc. Unless there is any temperature change or any chemical process happening, All other forms of Energies excluding mentioned in question remain constant, Hence they will anyways cancel out when you apply conservation equation, So just applying Mechanical conservation On kinetic and potential energies such as gravitational and elastic will anyways work

Comment: The potential here should create a classical motion and lead to a CM equation, any other potential related to QM cannot be associated to the mechanical total energy because there is no real motion at that level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seen the **mechanical energy** of a system defined as **the sum of its kinetic and potential energies**. What forms of potential energy are included in this definition?  Gravitational and elastic potential energy are the ones typically featured in textbook examples but what about chemical potential energy or electrical potential energy?  They don't seem to fit under the umbrella of mechanical energy.

I hope this is not a question about what the word "mechanical" means.

But, anyway, if you want to avoid the word "mechanical" you could use the word "total" instead.

The "total energy" $E$ is the "kinetic energy" $T$ plus the "potential energy" $U$.

The kinetic energy, in classical non-relativistic mechanics, for a system of $N$ particles, is *defined* as:
$$
T = \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{2}m_i |\vec v_i|^2
$$

The kinetic energy obeys the Lagrange equation (now written for generalized coordinates $q_i$):
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_i} - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i} = F_i\;.
$$

Nothing has yet been said about "potential energy," right?

OK, so, **if the force $F_i$ is conservative**, this means it can be written as $F_i = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}$, **where $U$ is called the "potential energy."**

Anytime you have a conservative force, you can introduce a potential energy that is appropriate to include in the "total" or "mechanical" energy in classical mechanics.

Indeed, when we introduce such a potential, we find a different form of the Lagrange equations:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = 0\;,
$$
where $L = T - U$.

---

For example, for a single particle of charge $q$ in a conservative electric field, one can introduce an electric potential $\phi$:
$$
\vec E = -\nabla \phi\;
$$
The force is $q\vec E$ and so the electric potential energy is $U=q\phi$.

It is perfectly reasonable and common to call this $U$ a part of the total mechanical energy:
$$
E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + q\phi(\vec x)
$$

Comment: Total energy would include internal energy (including or also known as thermal energy) which is distinct from mechanical energy.
So, I'm afraid that I am asking for what the word mechanical means and I was hoping that it wasn't the sort of question that is best settled by an opinion pole but if it is that's good to know.

Comment: Oh, okay. Yeah, I think that's mostly a matter of opinion. To some extent "**mechanical**" might sound like it has to involve gears and levers and such, but "classical **mechanics**" and "quantum **mechanics**" could also be described as "mechanical." As could "statistical **mechanics**." So it really can be either broad or narrow depending on various things.

Comment: Maybe there's some standard definition some textbook uses, but it seems like it would have to be pretty arbitrary and useless.